# Validating match and unique using Symfony validator

Tags: php, validation, symfony, silex

I'm using Silex for a small project, but I'm not sure how to validate two matching password fields, also check for the uniqueness of an email using a database connection. I haven't been able to figure it out in SF2 docs.

Possible someone can give me a hint or sample?

Thanks in advance

```
if ('POST' === $user->getMethod()) {

    $constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
        'name' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(array('message' => 'Name shouldnt be blank'))),
        'username' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\MinLength(3)),
        'email' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Email()),
        'password' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\MinLength(6)),
        'password2' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\MinLength(6)),
        'terms' => array(new Assert\True()),
    ));

    $errors = $app['validator']->validateValue($user->request->all(), $constraint); 

    if (!count($errors)) {
    //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't use Silex myself but in S2 you have a UniqueEntity constraint (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) for the unique email and a Repeated field for the password (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html)

Comment: Switched to using Symfony forms as it adds some functionality :) Still in doubt how to work the uniqueness tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see in the comments that you already switched to Sf2 forms. I guess you found the `RepeatedType` field, which is best for the repeated password field of a registration form - it has a built-in check to verify that the two values match.

Your other problem is checking the uniqueness of an email address. Here's the relevant part of my registration form:

```
<?php

namespace Insolis\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $app = $options["app"];

        $builder->add("email", "email", array(
            "label"         =>  "E-mail address",
            "constraints"   =>  array(
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Email(),
                new Assert\Callback(array(
                    "methods"   =>  array(function ($email, ExecutionContext $context) use ($app) {
                        if ($app["user"]->findByEmail($email)) {
                            $context->addViolation("Email already used");
                        }
                    }),
                )),
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        parent::setDefaultOptions($resolver);
        $resolver->setRequired(array("app"));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "register";
    }
}
```

Notes:

- `$app` is injected so I have access to the dependency injection container
- `$app["user"]` is my User table via [KnpRepositoryServiceProvider](https://github.com/KnpLabs/RepositoryServiceProvider)
- `$app["user"]->findByEmail` returns null or a user record