# Silex/Symfony Form validator : ensure a value is unique

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, silex

I use Silex with Form and Validator provider.

I have got a very simple register form :

- username
- password
- confirmation of password

The username must be unique, how to check that ?

This my code :

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')
      ->add('username', 'text', array(
        'constraints' => array(
          new Assert\NotBlank(),
          new Assert\Length(array('min' => 6, 'max' => 20)))
        ))
      ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
        'constraints' => array(
          new Assert\NotBlank(),
          new Assert\Length(array('min' => 6, 'max' => 20))
          )
        ))
      ->getForm();
```

With Symfony, I know there is the *UniqueEntity* constraint but it comes with Doctrine and I only use Doctrine DBAL (Silex provider)

I think I can use the *Callback* constraint but I would like to know if there is a better solution than write a callback with a SQL query... or write my own *Constraint* object

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating match and unique using Symfony validator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641897/validating-match-and-unique-using-symfony-validator)

Comment: Not really a duplicate, I ask for the "best" way to achieve my goal: "Add a constraint on a field to check if the value is unique". I mentionned in my question two ways : Create my own constraint or use callback. Which one is the best ? Are there other ways ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I decided to create my own Constraint because I can reuse it for email for example.
So, this is my implementation :

UniqueEntry.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Ensure a value is unique in the database
 *
 * @author Thomas KELLER
 */

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\MissingOptionsException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class UniqueEntry extends Constraint {

  public $notUniqueMessage = 'This value already exist in the database';
  public $dbal_connection;
  public $table;
  public $field;

  public function __construct($options = null)
  {
    parent::__construct($options);

    if ($this->dbal_connection === null)
      throw new MissingOptionsException(sprintf('The option "dbal_connection" is mandatory for constraint %s', __CLASS__), array('dbal_connection'));

    if (!$this->dbal_connection instanceof \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection)
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The option "dbal_connection" must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Connection for constraint %s', __CLASS__));

    if ($this->table === null)
      throw new MissingOptionsException(sprintf('The option "table" is mandatory for constraint %s', __CLASS__), array('table'));

    if (!is_string($this->table) OR $this->table == '')
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The option "table" must be a valid string for constraint %s', __CLASS__));

    if ($this->field === null)
      throw new MissingOptionsException(sprintf('The option "field" is mandatory for constraint %s', __CLASS__), array('field'));

    if (!is_string($this->field) OR $this->field == '')
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The option "field" must be a valid string for constraint %s', __CLASS__));
  }
}
```

UniqueEntryValidator.php:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class UniqueEntryValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
  public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
  {
    $query = sprintf('SELECT `%s` FROM `%s` WHERE `%s` = ?',
      $constraint->field,
      $constraint->table,
      $constraint->field);

    $stmt = $constraint->dbal_connection->executeQuery($query, array($value));

    if ($stmt->fetch())
      $this->context->addViolation($constraint->notUniqueMessage);
  }
}
```

I post my implementation to have suggestion so feel free to comment it ;)

Comment: A slightly simpler way to achieve this would be to use the [Callback constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html), passing in a function like: `array('models\User', 'validateEmailUniqueness')`. It's not hugely simpler, but I find the requirement of defining two new classes just to create a single validator kind of tiresome.

Comment: I think there's some advantages: easier to reuse (you don't have to repeat the code in all controllers), less code in the controller, in Silex's spirit (follow the other validators conventions)

Comment: You also can use [FormEvents](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#c-the-formevents-post-submit-event) like `POST_SUBMIT`

Take a look at [BoltCMS](https://github.com/bolt/bolt) soruce code (for [v1.6.x](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/blob/release/1.6/app/src/Bolt/Controllers/Backend.php#L985) and [v2.x](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/blob/v2.1.1/src/Controllers/Backend.php#L1397) )